# Is list comprehension atomic?

Tags: python, thread-safety

This concerns the `_Status.getOps` method. I'm very new to multithreading and I'm not sure if I need to lock the thread for this method. Is list comprehension like this atomic or not? I can't imagine it's a single bytecode, but it seems clumsy.

```py
class _Status:
    '''A container object for formatting what we are doing in a 
    nice way. This way, the information about what we're doing
    is retained even after we're long-done doing it. '''
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.nextid = 0
        self.items = {}
        self.lock = threading.Rlock()
    
    def add(self, opStr)
        ''' Pass this method a string describing an operation and 
        we'll put it into the data struture, then return to you an
        id you can use to do things to this operation later. '''
        with self.lock:
            id = self._getid()
            # Store the operation
            self.items[id] = {
                'name': opStr
                'status': 'Initalizing',
                'errors': []
            }
            return id
            
    def getOps(self):
        ''' This method returns a list of strings describing what's
        going on right now. Also comes with some suggested colors 
        for displaying them. '''
        with self.lock:
            return ['{name}: {status}'.format(**op) for op in 
                [self.items[id] for id in sorted(self.items.keys()]]
            
    def clear(self):
        ''' This removes all stored operations--use with caution. '''
        self.items = {}
            
    def _updateOp(self, opId, opStatus):
        ''' This method needs an id to work with and a string which
        descibes the status of that id's operation. I'll update it
        if it can. This is a private method, we'll give aliases for
        it, however. '''
        with threading.Lock():
            # Do nothing if we can't find the item
            if id in self.items:
                return
            self.items[id]['status'] = opStatus         
            
    def _getid(self):
        ''' Internal method to increment the next id we hand out. '''
        id = hex(self.nextid)
        self.nextid += 1
        return id
```

Comment: Your concern is that `self.items` is modified during the list comprehension, right?

Comment: BTW `# Do nothing if we can't find the item`, `if id in self.items:` are you sure this shouldn't be `if id not in self.items`?

Comment: You also need to be concerned with whether `dict.keys()` or `sorted()` are atomic. I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, yes (restructured the code before copying & missed that, of course), and you're right--that't the actual concern. I'll keep the lock

Comment: In general, very few operations in Python are guaranteed to be atomic. If you assume nothing is, you'll be safe.